# ServiceStack HEAD request ContentLength not getting set

Tags: http, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack (4.0.31) with mono and I am using raw streaming, which means my DTO is of the form:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class S3Request  : IRequiresRequestStream{ 
    public string Path{ get; set; }
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

I implement all HTTP request types: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE.  I need HEAD to respond just as defined in RFC 2616 where it says:

"The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request."

This should be simple from within ServiceStack, but it has proven difficult given my understanding so far.  For example, if I try the following, it almost gives me what I want (for the Head request response):

```
Response.EndRequestWithNoContent();
```

However this does not work because it zeroes out the Content-Length header field, which is not consistent with the RFC (and my client).  If I do not make this call, then when I return the ServiceStack IResponse after having set Content-Length, I get default XML in the output, which is also not consistent with the RFC.  Also, I can't decorate my DTO or set a default for the route to not return XML because I must use the IRequiresRequestStream with a common route.

Can I use a response filter or something else to tell ServiceStack that this is  a HEAD response and not fill in XML, but also not remove my Content-Length?

Answer (score 0):

You can end the Request without resetting the `Content-Length` with just:

```
Response.EndRequest();
```

Comment: Response.EndRequest() did not work.  I tried it before as well as after setting Content-Length, as well as calling Response.EndRequest(false).  There is something downstream in ServiceStack that overrides and clears Content-Length if any kind of EndRequest() is called.  I am wondering if I can send or preserve the headers prior to EndRequest?  Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Here is a capture from tcpflow right over the wire:  127.000.000.001.01301-127.000.000.001.49146: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: OLS3 Server V1.0
Date: 7/9/2015 10:41:54 AM
Last-Modified: 2015-06-25T21:56:28.726Z
ETag: "565151bd2fb9f4ad4f48908e1471338a"
x-amz-meta-cb-modifiedtime: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:16:20 GMT
Vary: Accept
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.031 Unix/Mono
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100